# Monero standard client unspents

Tags: bitcoin

Is monero standard client stores unspents? Can I withdraw all unspents for specific address or should I implement my own database with these unspents?

Thankd for any help

Answer (score -1):

All data, including unspent amount, is stored on the Monero blockchain database, and each Monero client (daemon) stores its own version locally. When you spend money, you don't need to manage unspent outputs. You just specify the destination address, the amount, and the wallet will figure out which unspent outputs should be used.